# WxHaskell thinks my strings are 1 character long

Tags: haskell, wxwidgets

Whenever I use a string in WxHaskell, it thinks the string is one character (it only displays the first character). It only happens when using the WxHaskell functions, not functions like putStrLn.

For example, the bug happens in this code

```
module Main where
import Graphics.UI.WX

main = start hello
hello = do f <- frame [text := "Hello"]
           quit <- button f [text := "quit", on command := close f]
           set f [layout := widget quit]
```

It doesn't happen in this program:

```
module Main where

main = putStrLn "hello"
```

Comment: I get a form titled "Hello" with a single button labelled "quit" when running this program.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for help. I can't see what is wrong. I tried reinstalling, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this behavior a while back. Turned out to be a unicode issue. Recompiling with some sort of unicode flag fixed things, IIRC.

Comment: This sounds likely. An english letter in little-endian UTF-16 would look like a 1 character string if interpreted as zero-terminated UTF-8.

Comment: Do you know which flag it is?

Comment: I should probably say that I'm using GHC.

Comment: Hello? Do you know which flag it is?

Comment: See the question *[wxHaskell labels can't display full text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171375/wxhaskell-labels-cant-display-full-text)*.